# What is the maximum field strength of an electret?

Tags: electrostatics

What is the maximum practical (and available) field strength in modern electrets? Also, what, if any, are the theoretical limits?

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret):

> An electret is a stable dielectric material with a quasi-permanently
>   embedded static electric charge (which, due to the high resistance of
>   the material, will not decay for time periods of up to hundreds of
>   years) and/or a quasi-permanently oriented dipole polarization...
>   Historically, electrets were made by first melting a suitable
>   dielectric material such as a polymer or wax that contains polar
>   molecules, and then allowing it to re-solidify in a powerful
>   electrostatic field. The polar molecules of the dielectric align
>   themselves to the direction of the electrostatic field, producing a
>   dipole electret with a permanent electrostatic 'bias'. Modern
>   electrets are usually made by embedding excess charges into a highly
>   insulating dielectric, e.g. by means of an electron beam, a corona
>   discharge, injection from an electron, electric breakdown across a gap
>   or a dielectric barrier, etc.

Comment: Field strength where? Right next to the electret? Are you willing to make it and keep it in vacuum? Otherwise you have to worry about dielectric breakdown of the air itself.

Comment: I'll keep it in SF6